# Footer is not aligning at the bottom while using react-full-page

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using [`react-full-page`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-full-page) in my project. But while adding the `Footer` in the routes, the footer on visible in the second section of the page and is not going at the bottom of the page.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-minsky-rd9qm?file=/src/App.js)

I have included 2 routes, one `"/"`for home and the other `"/about"` for about.

Answer (score 0):

Your Footer component is after your fullPage element (you can see in inspect), but your fullPage element has a static height and your footer is after that, if you want your footer being after all element, in this case, you must add your footer into fullPage,

Like this,

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <FullPage>
        <Slide>
          <div style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
            <h1>Hi</h1>
          </div>
        </Slide>
        <Slide>
          <div style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
            <h1>Test Me</h1>
          </div>
        </Slide>
        <Slide>
          <div style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
            <h1>I am Home</h1>
          </div>
        </Slide>
        <Slide>
          <div style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
            <h1>I am Home</h1>
          </div>
        </Slide>
        <Slide>
          <Footer />
        </Slide>
      </FullPage>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: This will take full-screen size footer. Whereas I need a small one. Also, I have 8 pages, and repeating the `Footer` component will not be appropriate.